# Actionscript3 - Removing entry from Comobox Data Provider (XMLlist) when list entry is disabled

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, combobox

I am modifying code that I did not write and I have minimal experience with Actionscript.

Currently, menu items are greyed out when they are disabled. This is achieved through following classes:

1. `DisabledComboBox` (extends ComboBox)
2. `DisabledList` (extends List)
3. `DisabledListItemRenderer` (extends Label)

Menu constraints are stored in a large XML variable `MenuChoiceXML`. Each `DisabledComboBox` refers to an `XMLlist` which is a subset of `MenuChoiceXML` as its `DataProvider`. Each list entry within the `XMLlists` has an elementsID (integer).

Also within `MenuChoiceXML` is an `XMLlist` full menu constraints which are preassembled based on what is available in the database. They use the following form:

- selecting 15 constrains 5, 12, 23

In other words, selecting 15 in one `DisabledComboBox`, greys out 5,12, and 23 in other `DisabledComboBoxes`, and they can't be selected.

Rather than greying them out and disabling the MouseEvent that selects them, I would like to completely remove them from the `DataProvider` `XMLlist`.

These are what I believe to be the relevant bits of code:

**Item in constraint `XMLlist`**

```
<Constraints>
        <Cstr choice="DataProvider1" selectedValue="2" constrains="DataProvider2" denies="4,7,12" />
</Constraints>
```

**TotalStateofProgram.as**

> ```
>  public function applyConstraints():void
> {
>
>
>   // before updating menus all constrained menus enable all menu choices, then turn on restricted options
>
>   for each(var menulist:String in constrainedMenuList)
>   {
>       for each(var xmlentry:XML in MenuChoicesXML.descendants(menulist).MenuItem)
>       {
>           xmlentry.@enabled=true;
>       }
>   }
>
>   // Save constraints in XMLlist
>   var cstrs:XMLList = MenuChoicesXML.descendants("Constraints").Cstr;
>   // go through each contraint in list of constraints
>   for each(var cstr:XML in cstrs)
>   {
>       var choice:String = cstr.@choice;
>       var value:String = cstr.@selectedValue;
>
>       // for each constraint - find if it is required constraint selectedValue matches current selection
>       var applies:Boolean = (design.getData(choice) == value);
>       if(applies)
>       {
>           var menuname:String = cstr.@constrains;
>           var denies:String = cstr.@denies;
>           var deniesarray:Array = denies.split(',');
>
>           // Go throught items which are denied by selection
>           for(var i:int = 0; i<deniesarray.length;i++) 
>           {
>               var d:String = deniesarray[i];
>
>               // If something that is to be constrained is currently selected, unselect it from DisabledComboBox
>               if(design.getData(menuname) == d) 
>                   design.setData(menuname, "0"); // default elementsId for unselected is 0
>
>
>               // set disable menu choice for this elementsId  
>               (MenuChoicesXML.descendants(menuname).MenuItem.(@elementsId == d)).@enabled = "false";
>
>           } 
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

The preceding code resets all constraints, then uses the currently selected menu item to apply constraints to other menu items. The important bit is this line:

`(MenuChoicesXML.descendants(menuname).MenuItem.(@elementsId == d)).@enabled = "false";`

It appears to be looking up an item in an `XMLlist` and disabling it. Once disabled, this is seen by the `DisabledList` and `DisabledListItemRenderer` where the selected item is turned grey and the MouseEvent attached to it is disabled. (I will post the code which achieves this later, as I'm not 100% it's relevant)

I realize that `ComboBox.removeItem()` is normally used, but I am unsure how I can look up a `ComboBox` or `DataProvider` using the `elementsID` (as was done above).

Here are some questions I have:

- Can I look up the `ComboBox` that has the `XMLlist` entry in its `DataProvider` and use `ComboBox.removeItem()`? How?
- Can I use the fact that an `XMLlist` entry is disabled to remove it from the list?
- Is there another way I'm not considering?

I will work on summarizing the code that greys out the list entry of the `DataProvide`r. I am not sure if it's relevant because the greying out is performed on the text within the list which makes up the `DataProvider` for the `DisabledComboBox`, however I want to remove the element from the `DisabledCombobox` (which seems like less work).

**Possibly Relevant Code:**

DisabledComboBox.as

```
package com.cwmlib.controls
{
    import mx.controls.ComboBox;
    import mx.core.ClassFactory;
    import mx.events.FlexEvent;

    public class DisabledComboBox extends ComboBox
    {
        public function DisabledComboBox()
        {

            super();

            this.dropdownFactory = new ClassFactory(DisabledList);

            this.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(DisabledListItemRenderer);

        }
    }
}
```

DisabledList.as

```
package com.cwmlib.controls
{
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import mx.controls.ComboBox;
    import mx.core.ClassFactory;
    import mx.controls.List;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.IListItemRenderer;
    import mx.controls.listClasses.ListItemRenderer;

    public class DisabledList extends List
    {


        public function DisabledList()
        {

            super();
            this.itemRenderer = new ClassFactory(DisabledListItemRenderer);

        }

        private function itemDisable(event:MouseEvent):Boolean
        {
            var item:IListItemRenderer = mouseEventToItemRenderer(event);

            if (item != null && item.data != null
                 && ((item.data is XML && item.data.@enabled == 'false')
                || item.data.enabled==false || item.data.enabled=='false')
                ) 
            {
                  return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
                  return false;
            }

        }   
    }
}
```

DisabledListItemRenderer.as

```
package com.cwmlib.controls
{
    import mx.controls.Label;

    public class DisabledListItemRenderer extends Label
    {
        private var _enabled:Boolean = true;

        public function DisabledListItemRenderer()
        {

              super();

        }    



        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {

            if (value != null && ((value is XML && value.@enabled == 'false')
                || value.enabled == false || value.enabled == 'false')
            ){

                this._enabled = false;

            }
            else
            {
                  this._enabled = true;

            }

            super.data = value;

        }    



        override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
        {

            super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            if (!this._enabled) {
                textField.setColor(getStyle("disabledColor"));
            }
            else
            {
                textField.setColor(getStyle("color"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to remove some items in one combobox if you select something in another one? And probably display them again if you select something else? In this case a filterFunction sounds to be the right tool for that. Not tested but this will give you an idea:

```
// make a dedicated _myDataProvider for the filtered combobox and assign a filterfunction to it
_myDataProvider.filterFunction = filterCollection;

// Assign the dataProvider
filteredCombobox.dataProvider = _myDataProvider;

// filter the dataprovider when selection in the first combobox will change
selectionComboBox.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onComboBoxChange);


private function onComboBoxChange(e:Event):void
{
    // refresh the dataprovider, that will apply the filter
    _myDataProvider.refresh();
}

private function filterCollection(item:Object):Boolean
{
    // here you need to know the condition for the filter depending on the selection in the first combobox (prbably the selected item in the selection combobox?)
    // this filterCollection function will run trough each item in the _myDataProvider and return true (keep the item in the list) or false (the item will disappear)               
    if (condition)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Keep in mind that when the filter is applied the _myDataProvider will contain only currently visible items. If you'd need the full collection again you could reset the dataprovider with

```
_myDataprovider.filterFunction = null;
_myDataprvider.refresh();
```

---

EDIT:

This whole XML manipulation sounds like a pain to me. Get rid of the custom combo boxes and XML. Parse your XML and make two dataproviders - one for the selection combobox that will have value objects with this denies property:

```
public class SelectionVO
{
    public var label:String;
    public var denies:Array; // for example, ["2", "3", "4"];
}
```

And another one for the filtered combobox with a value object that will have the id to check if this item should be filtered out or not:

```
public class FilteredItemVO
{
    public var label:String;
    public var myID:String; // for example, "3"
}
```

And then when the selection combobox changes you filter the collection:

```
private function filterCollection(item:Object):Boolean
{
    var selectedVO:SelectionVO = selectionComboBox.selectedItem as SelectionVO;

    // show this item if its myID is NOT included in the selected vo's denies array
    if (selectedVO:SelectionVO.denies.indexOf(item.myID) == -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: This is most certainly the correct answer. I was hoping for a quick solution using the framework that exists, as a new version is going to be written in HTML5 and this will only be used for a short period.

Comment: Is it possible to look up the dataprovider in which an item in an XML list is contained in?

Comment: This is he easy solution :) You need to modify the dataprovider anyway to remove an item. So a better approach is to "hide" some items rather than removing them completely - this way you don't need to recreate it when you'll need the full list again. Sorry, I don't understand your second comment

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct about the `filterFunction()` vs `removeItem()`. Currently, the disabling (greying out) is done by implementing a custom `ComboBox` and overriding certain functions. My concern was that I could not apply the logic above in the same way. I am having some success implementing what you have suggested within the custom `ComboBox` (but there is still some strange behavior). If I can't figure it out, can I post an edit and ask for your input?

Comment: I see now that the code was taken directly from here: [link](http://www.stoimen.com/blog/2009/03/05/flex-3-combobox-disabled-options/) which points to here: [link](http://wmcai.blog.163.com/blog/static/4802420088945053961/) At the time these constraints are created, I do not have convenient access to the `dataProviders`.

Comment: I've edited my response for better code formatting - just get rid of all this XML manipulation stuff to make life easier :)

Comment: Hello again. I agree about the XML nonsense. The only issue is that the back end code which generates all the menu entries and constraints (which there are a lot of) creates these XML structures. Given the time frame, that is not an option. I have (almost) successfully implemented my desired scenario. The only problem now is that after filtering. The indexes no longer match. For example say all menu options are removed except 0 and 3. In the new filtered version the index of 3 is now 1 and the data to go with it no longer matches.

Comment: Ok, with your help, I figured it out. The guy who programed this looked up the original menu item when calling `onComboBoxChange` rather than get the info from the currently selected value. What a mess.

Comment: Glad it helped. But still, parsing the XML and make ArrayCollections out of it shouldn't take a lot of time - maybe 2 hours ? But if it works - well then :).